# Cordova : Download file where URL takes request parameter

Tags: java, android, cordova, download

I am working on a Cordova application which internally is our webapp. The webapp is created with Spring platform. We have a functionality where you can download files which returns a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`. Normally, in a browser, it's already sufficient, but in the app, the download is simply not working, I have also added the plugins as shown below. What am I missing?

Please note : The URL is dynamically generated for downloading files, and unlike other posts on SO, where the URL is constant.

Plugin list :

```
cordova plugin list
com.bandpad.cordova.microphone 1.2.1 "Microphone"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.3 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-webrtc 0.1.1 "WebRTC"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.2dev "LocalNotification"
```

What am I missing? Kindly let me know. I am new to Cordova.